# Character Encoding Python 2.7.6 yQT Displaying chr(128)

Tags: python, unicode, pyqt

I am running on a Windows system. Though I would like to be cross-platform. Right now I'll be happy to solve the question.

My test code is:

```
for n in range(32, 255):
    if n%16 == 0:
        xStr = xStr + '\n'
    xStr = xStr + str(n) + ':' + chr(n) + '\t'

form.lstResponse.addItem(xStr)  (This is a pyQT 4.8.5 QListWidget)
```

I am trying to use the symbol 'Arial' 128 which looks like a 'C" with two horizontal lines through it.

But, it appears that characters between 128 and 160 are missing?

How do I use the characters between 128 and 160?

All this Unicode stuff is quite baffling to me...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

First, the

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Has to be the first line. I have not tried all possibilities, But, moving it down the file kills it.

When the above code is included the following lines work as desired.

```
s = u'€'
xStr = QString(s)
form.lstResponse.addItem(xStr)
form.lstResponse.addItem(u'€')
```